# Ruby on Rails: Fetch database result and search through results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fetch

I have a set of IDs for a table called "brands". I want to fetch the name column for each record in the brand table without having to re-query the database using Brand.find(brand_id). Instead, is there a way to store the database results into a variable and query the variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already collected the records in a var @brands, you can use

```
name = @brands.find {|b| b.id == brand_id}.name
```

not a query

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array of all `Brand`s for a `brand_id`

```
Brand.find(:all, :conditions => ["brand_id = ?", brand_id])
```

For a collection of `brand_id`s

```
Brand.find(:all, :conditions => ["brand_id IN (?)", [brand_id1, brand_id2]])
```

HTH

Comment: Is there a way to then query that result to get the "name" field, such as `returnedBrands.find(aSpecificID).name` where returnedBrands is an array containing `Brand.find(:all)`?

Comment: As others have pointed out, you may use `select`, `pluck` functions of array to retrieve specific records. e.g. `Brand.find(:all, :conditions => ["brand_id = ?", brand_id]).select {|record| record.name if record.id == someID}`

Comment: If you need only specific columns, you may add `select` attribute in `find` method. e.g. `Brand.find(:all, :select => "id, name", :conditions => ["brand_id = ?", brand_id]).select {|record| record.name if record.id == someID}`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can write a method in your model brand.  
    def get_associated_brand  
        b = self.brand_id  
       brand = Brand.find(b).name  
   end  

From your view just call this method so that in your view you ll get brand name instead of ID like
```

brand.get_associated_brand

instead of

```
brand.brand_id
```

Answer (score 0):

About what was commented on @Harsh Gupta's answers, maybe

```
@filtered_brands = Brand.where(id: <some_id>)
```

Then you can access all info of each brand in a regular each loop.